# How do I prevent MSI U100 Netbook from Freezing Upon Resume from Suspend?

Tags: suspend-resume

Fresh install of Oneiric on U100. Previously had Mint 9 on it, which slept and resumed properly. Under 11.10 suspend leads to very unpredictable results. Sometimes I can type my password and get back the display.

Sometimes it will freeze and not let me wake it up with the keyboard or mouse. Sometimes it will come back, but not let me do anything. In all cases after suspend, wireless won't work.